# How does the time taken for backpropagation change with the increase in neurons?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

This is a question I come across a lot in interviews but I don't understand how and what the answer is:-

If we have a neural net, and we double the neurons in it, how does the time taken for backpropagation change? does it increase by

1. 2 times
2. 4 times
3. 8 times
4. 16 times

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is that time complexity is related to the number of operations needed to perform all the steps of backpropagation. You can find an example workthrough here:
https://medium.com/swlh/computational-complexity-of-neural-networks-38c01e7e566a

For a 4 layer NN it seems the complexity is O(n⁵), where n is the number of nodes of each layer (also n is the same for every layer in that example).